# Internet Explorer and Java security

Tags: java, security, internet-explorer, applet

I want to know if applets simply won't run anymore in IE.

I've searched quite a bit but the answer seems to keep changing based on versions and when this question is asked.  So I'm looking for a simple authoritative answer.

Here's my setup:

- Running IE 11 on Windows 7
- Java 1.8.0_60 is configured as the Java runtime environment
- No other Java versions are installed
- "Enable Java content in browser" is checked
- Java security setting is "high"
- Site (local file for now) is specified in the Java security exception site list

I realize Java will no longer work in Chrome but is it still possible or not (using recent versions above) in IE as of today?

**UPDATE:**

I've added the security requirements to the manifest and I've self-signed the jar file but something still isn't quite right as the applet doesn't display its output.

Here's the manifest as it exists in the jar file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: test
Permissions: all-permissions
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_60
Created-By: 1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)

Name: HelloApplet.class
SHA-256-Digest: wkK+EUOV7eaecddcrIwBnjeZ+95GyyuK7OiVXR4XJ+4=
```

And here's the applet code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloApplet extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

And here's the web page **(UPDATED TO USE APPLET TAG)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <applet code = 'HelloApplet' 
        archive = 'HelloApplet.jar'
        width = 300
        height = 300>
        <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions" />
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Use applet tag instead of object https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated the web page to use the applet tag (see above code).  There must be something still not correct.  Is there something else that needs to be changed?

Comment: Looks alright. Maybe it will help. Open the Java Control Panel, in “General” tab, there should be a “Temporary Files Settings”. Go to “Settings” and delete temporary files. I recommend you to uncheck the “Keep temporary files …” for development purposes. Go to Security and check if the “Enable java content ..” is checked and if security level in not set on “Very High”. Clean the browser cache as well. Restart browser.

Comment: Please ignore the " Go to Security" sentence of previous comment.

Comment: Appreciate all the help. I've make the changes in Java Control Panel and cleared the browser cache.  Unfortunately still no output in the browser.

In addition I've done the following:
1. rebooted my laptop
2. checked the console in IE developer tools to make sure no errors display
3. used appletviewer to verify the applet actually displays successfully

Not sure what else to try here.

Comment: Try to turn the "Show Console" option in Java Control Panel / Advanced / Java console. I think browser's restart is needed after that. Check the console for output. Change log level if there is none ( press 5 as far I can remember).

Comment: Looking at the Java console is a good idea and should be helpful.  Unfortunately I can't get it to display.  So I tried to find a file that contains the console output but haven't found it yet.

Comment: Try the the Oracle test page  http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp. You should see the prompt, then click the details button. Make sure that IE is your default browser. Follow the instructions (reinstall Java). After that steps you should at least be able to see console and error message.

Comment: Wow.  It's actually working now.  The applet displays it's output and the Java Console is appearing too.  Looks like reinstalling Java did the trick.  Thanks for following up until this got resolved.  That was impressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applets are still working in IE. But from 7u51 Java version, there have been new security requirements for the MANIFEST.MF file.

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias

In short, you need at least to define Permissions, Codebase attributes.

Code snipped from my applet (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in jar file):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: app-name
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_79
Permissions: all-permissions
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
```

Addition requirements depend on access permissions type the applet requires (all-permissions or sandbox).

More info:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm trying to get this to work and will provide an update.